# Passing HTML table row data in Firefox not working properly

Tags: php, html, dom

I have been working with HTML/JS for about a week.

I am using XMLHttpRequest to load a table on my main page, allowing the user to refresh the table with new data. From the table I have created, I am retrieving additional data into a second XMLHttpRequest on the form. I am passing the data via the onclick event of the table row. Here is the basic code:

```
function test(tablerow)
{
//get the rowindex for the row

var myIndex = tablerow.rowIndex;

//get the cell data for the clicked row in the first column

// original var company_id = table1.rows.item(myIndex).cells.item(0).textContent;

var my_id = table1.rows.item(myIndex).cells.item(0).textContent;

alert(my_id);
}
```

This works just fine when I load the table for the first time, but when I load a new table, it seems to be saving the previous table data.

Example:

First table:

```
ID
--
1
2
3
4
5
```

When clicking on the row, the response gets the ID properly. But. when I load the second table:

```
ID
--
6
7
8
9
10
```

When click on row 1, I get 1 as a response for the cell data. 2, for the second row, etc... It is getting the responses for the original table data. As mentioned earlier, this does not occur in Chrome or IE. I get the proper data.

I have created a small test case which exhibits the behavior I am seeing.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, and why this is only happening in Firefox?

### Test Case:

Page1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test(tablerow)
{
//get the rowindex for the row

var myIndex = tablerow.rowIndex;

//get the cell data for the clicked row in the first column

// original var company_id = table1.rows.item(myIndex).cells.item(0).textContent;

var my_id = table1.rows.item(myIndex).cells.item(0).textContent;

alert(my_id);
}

function getPage()
{
HttpRequest = PostXmlHttpObject();

HttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (HttpRequest.readyState==4 && HttpRequest.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=HttpRequest.responseText;
    }
}

HttpRequest.open("GET","page2.php?table="+1, true);
HttpRequest.send();

}

function getPage2()
{
HttpRequest = PostXmlHttpObject();

HttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (HttpRequest.readyState==4 && HttpRequest.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=HttpRequest.responseText;
    }
}

HttpRequest.open("GET","page2.php?table="+2, true);
HttpRequest.send();

}

function PostXmlHttpObject()
{
var HttpRequest = false;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { // Mozilla, Safari,...
    HttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(HttpRequest.overrideMimeType)
    {
        // set type accordingly to anticipated content type
        HttpRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
    }
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{ // IE
    try{
        HttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){}
    }
}
if(!HttpRequest)
{
    alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
}
return HttpRequest;
}

</script>

<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1">

<input type="button" value="Get XML Page 1" onclick="getPage()"/>
<input type="button" value="Get XML Page 2" onclick="getPage2()"/>

<br /><br />

<div id="divTable"><b></b></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Page2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<?php 

$table_id = $_GET["table"];

if ($table_id == 1)
{
?>

<form name="form2" id="form2">
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
</tr>

<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>5</td>
</tr>

</table>
<?php 
}
else
{
?>
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
</tr>

<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="test(this);">
<td>10</td>
</tr>

</table>
<?php 
}
?>

</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your test function like this and check

```
function test(tablerow)
{
    alert(tablerow.cells.item(0).innerHTML);
    alert(tablerow.cells[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine. Both alerts respond with the same number, the proper column data.Thanks. Any idea why Firefox doesn't like the previous code, but IE and Chrome do?

Comment: Does Firefox keep the table data cached somewhere, so when I referenced the data by table1 it used the old data? That's my guess, but I wonder why IE and Chrome behave differently.